# Flutter: Live activity not showing on lock screen and dynamic island

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode15, widgetliveactivity

Good day everyone! I have a problem related to Lve Activity, I use this ([live activity plugin](https://github.com/istornz/flutter_live_activities)) plugin to build Lve Activity. However, my activity View is not showing either on lock screen or dynamic island, however, as I can see from the logs, the activity is created and I get my activity ID: (flutter: Activity update:

```
ActiveActivityUpdate(activityId: 57F62DC6-EA5F-4F8C- BC88-263494234146, activityToken: 808717dd5dbb0594ac36e4e9a592e704e2ec15a5a0000524eeafa27c7b3a01eb7a23a73f3b8062e002f33c364318177631ff2af386513 53961f4fd3259b4bb03e7fbb914e1812f5671aa2ff835d15099e444255522f3267da9baac3c60aa7b642a84002f579ae468a17796c12e8f9c87cd2a702bf768f09ddbb2 8aaac562b491))
```

. This problem occurred after upgrading to Xcode 15, maybe someone has encountered this problem and has a good solution?

Comment: Hey Stepan, were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Hey Cedric,

Yes, in my case, the problem was that I used the Flavors approach and the `bundleId` did not match. I registered with AppStoreConnect `bundleId` without `.dev` prefix, and tested on a build that had `bundleId` with `.dev` prefix.